# Can't scape backslashes with sed

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I'm trying to find \STRING1\ and replace it with \STRING2\ (mind the backslashes)

I tried the following:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/\\STRING1\\/\\STRING2\\/g" {} \;
```

It didn't work and I got this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unterminated `s' command

I searched the web and people recommend adding two backslashes to any backslash I'd like to search and/or replace. So I tried this:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/\\\STRING1\\\/\\\STRING2\\\/g" {} \;
```

I got no errors this time, but it didn't do anything. What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
> echo "some text\STRING1\ and some more \STRING1\andeven more" | sed 's/\\STRING1\\/\\STRING2\\/g'
some text\STRING2\ and some more \STRING2\andeven more
```

Comment: I think you're not taking the find into account

Comment: Yes. Always use single-quotes for command arguments in the shell unless you want the shell to expand a variable or perform some other text substitution within the argument. Then, double-quotes are what you want.

Comment: @user1336449: yes, I figured you'd be able to figure that part. Just replace your double-quotes with single quotes in your statement. No other change should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quote your `sed` command with double quotes, then you have to use *quadruple* backslashes to get a single literal backslash in the pattern:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/\\\\STRING1\\\\/\\\\STRING2\\\\/g" {} \;
```

This is because backslash is a live metacharacter for double-quoted shell strings, so the shell cuts the number of backslashes in half and then so does `sed`.  Alternatively, use single quotes as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a single quoted string.
If you use double quotes, the string is preprocessed by your shell and sed receives only single backslashes.